# Carrying a touch event from beginning to end in Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, sprite-kit, sprite, touch-event

I am trying to create an app that creates a sprite node when the touch begins, drags it when the user's finger moves, and drops it when the touch has ended. What I have now simply creates a new sprite for **every** new touch location:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKSpriteNode *gamePiece = [self pickObject];
    gamePiece.position = location;
    gamePiece.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    [self addChild:gamePiece];


}
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKSpriteNode *gamePiece = [self pickObject];
    gamePiece.position = location;
    gamePiece.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    [self addChild:gamePiece];


}


}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKSpriteNode *gamePiece = [self pickObject];
    gamePiece.position = location;
    gamePiece.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

    [self addChild:gamePiece];


}


}
```

How do I carry the same, single sprite node across the touch methods? I have searched far and wide for tutorials, but nothing seems to fit exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by maintaining an instance variable for the touch as well as the SKSpriteNode associdated with that touch.

```
@implementation MyScene
{

UITouch *currentTouch;
SKSpriteNode *currentGamePiece;

}
```

Then, modify the touch delegates as follows:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode *gamePiece = [self pickObject];
        gamePiece.position = location;
        gamePiece.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

        [self addChild:gamePiece];

        currentTouch = touch;
        currentGamePiece = gamePiece;


    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if ([touch isEqual:currentTouch])
        {
            currentGamePiece.position = location;
        }

    }

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if ([touch isEqual:currentTouch])
        {
            currentGamePiece.position = location;
            currentGamePiece = nil;
            currentTouch = nil;

        }

}
```